# DreamScene on multiple monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors on my work computer, and I'd like to use a different DreamScene wallpaper on each monitor. Is there a simple way to set this up? I considered combining the videos into one, but they're two different lengths (and the longer one isn't divisible by the shorter one), so that won't easily work. I'm not sure what else I could try.

I used [DreamScene Seven](http://www.dreamsceneseven.com/) to enable the system on my computer.

Comment: Windows 7 does not support dreamscene out of the box. There are several hacks to get it working anyway, but it helps to know which one you used.

Comment: I used [DreamScene Seven](http://www.dreamsceneseven.com/). Sorry for not including that information initially.

Comment: this is an unsupported hack. If it doesn't work you have to except this.